# Disabling Entry Field by clicking on Radio-buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn how to click one radio button and it will be disabled on the entry field and vice versa on the other. I can't seem to figure out what am I doing wrong. I figured a if-elif statement will work, but no luck. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Attached is a simplified version of my code.

```
from tkinter import *

def foo():
    return v.get()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')

v = StringVar()
v.set('T-xy')

Radiobutton(root,text='P-xy',variable=v,value='P-xy',command=foo).pack()
Radiobutton(root,text='T-xy',variable=v,value='T-xy',command=foo).pack()

if foo() == 'P-xy':
    Entry1 = Entry(root,state=DISABLED).pack()
    Entry2 = Entry(root).pack()
elif foo() == 'T-xy':
    Entry1 = Entry(root).pack()
    Entry2 = Entry(root,state=DISABLED).pack() 
    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the entries first and perform the enabling/disabling of the entries inside `foo()` function:

```
from tkinter import *

def foo():
    val = v.get()
    Entry1.config(state=NORMAL if val == 'T-xy' else DISABLED)
    Entry2.config(state=NORMAL if val == 'P-xy' else DISABLED)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')

v = StringVar()
v.set('T-xy')

Radiobutton(root,text='P-xy',variable=v,value='P-xy',command=foo).pack()
Radiobutton(root,text='T-xy',variable=v,value='T-xy',command=foo).pack()

Entry1 = Entry(root)
Entry1.pack()

Entry2 = Entry(root,state=DISABLED)
Entry2.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I do appreciate it!